# Cheapest way of binding local variable to closure

Tags: c++, c++11

I believe following to be a cheapest way of binding local variable to closure:

```
void ByRValueReference(A&& a) {
}

std::function<void ()> CreateClosureByRValueReference() {
  A a;
  std::function<void ()> f = std::bind(&ByRValueReference, std::move(a)); // !!!
  return f;
}
```

However, it does not compile under Clang 3.1:

```
error: no viable conversion from '__bind<void (*)(A &&), A>' to 'std::function<void ()>'
```

and gcc 4.6.1:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1778:2: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(A))(A&&)>) ()’
```

Am I violating the standard or it's just broken standard libraries?

Comment: I think its `function<void(A&&)>`.

Comment: What is actually a little costly here is `std::function`. If you really care about efficiency I would return `decltype(std::bind(...))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design of `std::bind`. The full specification is in 20.8.9.1.2 Function template bind [func.bind.bind] but in this case the last bullet of paragraph 10 (which describes how the bound parameters are used) applies:

> — otherwise, the value is `tid` and its type `Vi` is `TiD cv &`

So in other words, `std::move(a)` will result in the call wrapper storing an `A` (from move construction), and then when `operator()` is used this member will be forwarded *as an lvalue* (with additional cv-qualifiers matching the cv-qualifiers of the call wrapper, but I digress). Even though it was passed as an rvalue.

This kind of mismatch can be solved via a lambda:

```
std::bind([](A& a) { ByRValueReference(std::move(a)); }, std::move(a))
```

This can be argued that it's more explicit that further calls to the resulting call wrapped are dubious (since the `A` member is liable to have been moved from), but I'm not overly fond of the behaviour of `std::bind` as a whole.

Comment: If you're going with a lambda, you might as well return `[&a](){...}` directly and save yourself the bind...

Comment: @KerrekSB This has different semantics than the call to `std::bind` and in the OP's case will lead to UB.

Comment: Can't believe such a simple need requires such a verbose solution. My actual problem was storing std::unique_ptr inside closure, guess I have to fall back to std::shared_ptr.

Comment: @mmotorny You should be able to use `std::unique_ptr` in tandem with `std::bind`. The problem is only for invocation, and the fix I presented should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, lambdas aren't available in gcc 4.4 shipped with Android NDK.

Comment: @mmotorny You can write a `template<typename Ret, typename Arg, Ret (&ref)(Arg)> Ret move_adaptor(Arg arg) { return ref(std::move(arg)); }` adaptor and use it like so: `std::bind(&move_adaptor<void, A&, ByRValueReference>, std::move(a))` or any other usual solution that works in lieu of lambdas (functors, Boost.Phoenix, etc.).